# Reference/certified data set to compare custom software results

Tags: dataset, t-test, p-value

I am currently developing a software application that runs and generates results several statistical tests using .Net libraries. I have been comparing my results to R and another (non free) statistical package. For ANOVA test I can compare against NIST data sets, however I was wondering if there were any similar data sets accompanied with "industrial standard" certified p-values I could use for T-Tests and other statistical tests?